# Handling map of files in c++

Tags: c++

I need to write to a bunch of files simultaneously, so I decided to use `map <string, ofstream>`.

```
map<string, ofstream> MyFileMap;
```

I take a `vector<string> FileInd`, which consists of, say `"a" "b" "c"`, and try to open my files with:

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it = FileInd.begin(); iter != FileInd.end(); ++it){
    ...
    MyFileMap[*it].open("/myhomefolder/"+(*it)+".");
}
```

I get the error

```
request for member 'open' in ..... , which is of non-class type 'std::ofstream*'
```

I've tried to switch to

```
map<string, ofstream*> MyFileMap;
```

But it didn't work either.

Could anyone help?

Thanks.

**Clarification:**

I've tried both

`map<string, ofstream> MyFileMap;`
`map<string, ofstream*> MyFileMap;`

with both

`.open`
`->open`

neither of 4 variants work.

**Solution (suggested in Rob's code below):**

Basically, I forgot "new", the following works for me:

```
map<string, ofstream*> MyFileMap;
MyFileMap[*it] = new ofstream("/myhomefolder/"+(*it)+".");
```

Comment: You want `->open`, not `.open`. The `operator[]` on a vector returns something that acts like a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/

Comment: Sorry, I meant on a `map`, not on a `vector`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::map<std::string, std::ofstream>` can't possibly work, because `std::map` requires its data type to be Assignable, which `std::ofstream` isn't. In the alternative, the data type must be a pointer to ofstream -- either a raw pointer or a smart pointer.

Here is how I would do it, using C++11 features:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (int ac, char **av)
{
  // Convenient access to argument array
  std::vector<std::string> fileNames(av+1, av+ac);

  // If I were smart, this would be std::shared_ptr or something
  std::map<std::string, std::ofstream*> fileMap;

  // Open all of the files
  for(auto& fileName : fileNames) {
    fileMap[fileName] = new std::ofstream("/tmp/xxx/"+fileName+".txt");
    if(!fileMap[fileName] || !*fileMap[fileName])
      perror(fileName.c_str());
  }

  // Write some data to all of the files
  for(auto& pair : fileMap) {
    *pair.second << "Hello, world\n";
  }

  // Close all of the files
  // If I had used std::shared_ptr, I could skip this step
  for(auto& pair : fileMap) {
    delete pair.second;
    pair.second = 0;
  }
}
```

and the 2nd verse, in C++03:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (int ac, char **av)
{
  typedef std::map<std::string, std::ofstream*> Map;
  typedef Map::iterator Iterator;

  Map fileMap;

  // Open all of the files
  std::string xxx("/tmp/xxx/");
  while(av++,--ac) {
    fileMap[*av] = new std::ofstream( (xxx+*av+".txt").c_str() );
    if(!fileMap[*av] || !*fileMap[*av])
      perror(*av);
  }

  // Write some data to all of the files
  for(Iterator it = fileMap.begin(); it != fileMap.end(); ++it) {
    *(it->second) << "Hello, world\n";
  }

  // Close all of the files
  for(Iterator it = fileMap.begin(); it != fileMap.end(); ++it) {
    delete it->second;
    it->second = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply and a neat example. I forgot "new".

Comment: as cppcoreguidelines suggest raw pointer is not recommanded as best practice. Is there any other way?