# How to create a map of std::ofstream objects

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, file-writing

How should I add std::ofstream objects to a map of std::ofstream objects in c++?

I have tried solutions from other related questions, but I keep getting a segmentation fault. The problem is occurring in my openFile function.

I found another question relating to this, and tried using map::emplace, but I got a segmentation fault: `36817 Segmentation fault: 11`
[Is it possible to handle std::ofstream with std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072678/is-it-possible-to-handle-stdofstream-with-stdmap)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<int, std::ofstream> writeFiles::fileMap = {};

void writeFiles::openFile (int num) {
    fileMap.emplace(num, std::ofstream(getName(num))); // This is where the problem is
}

std::string writeFiles::getName (int num) {
    return "./temp/matrix/matrix" + std::to_string(num) + ".txt";
}
```

Comment: **Where** does the segfault happen? How does the other question not help you? What do you not know how to do? "Please fix this" is not a question

Comment: The segmentation fault is in the openFile function, and the solution for the other question said to use the emplace function, which is resulting in the segmentation fault.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you should be using a map of strings and not a map of ofstreams. load the string into the ofstream when you are ready to use it.

Comment: I am running a program that writes thousands of lines of text one line at a time, and to multiple files. I am trying to make the code more efficient by only opening each file once, at the start of the code.

Comment: @Matthew I think that defeats the purpose of using the map